# Mock return of chained method with spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I've been stuck on this for a bit. Is it possible to mock new URL(url).openStream() to return a file.gz? I am using spock to try to do this.

```
public class DownloadFile {
public  BufferedReader downloadGzipCsvFile(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    if (UrlValidator.getInstance().isValid(url)){
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new URL(url).openStream())));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    } else{
        throw new MalformedURLException("Supplied URL: " + url + " is an invalid URL");
    }
    return br;
}
}
```

Test class

```
class DownloadFileSpec extends Specification{

def "Should return buffered reader for url for gzip csv file"(){
    given:
    String url = "http://www.test.com"
    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile()

    when:
    BufferedReader br = downloadFile.downloadGzipCsvFile(url)
    _.openStream() << new FileInputStream("../../../../resources/test_data.csv.gz")

    then:
    br.ready()
}
}
```

Or would I be better writing a private method that would return a stream?

Comment: Why don't you stand up a server, and pass the URL of that to the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with testability is almost always the same: no dependency injection. This case is no different. Here the concrete problem at hand is that you cannot simply provide a `file://...` URL because you use Apache Commons Validate which yields `false` for `isValid(url)`.

The solution is to enable your class to inject a `UrlValidator` via a setter or an additional constructor. I am choosing the setter approach in my sample code. I even made the setter package-scoped if you do not like a public setter, so you can just put your test into the same package as the original class (which is common practice anyway) in order to access it.

Now just inject a mock during the test and happily use a file URL:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class DownloadFile {
  private UrlValidator urlValidator = UrlValidator.getInstance();

  void setUrlValidator(UrlValidator urlValidator) {
    this.urlValidator = urlValidator;
  }

  public BufferedReader downloadGzipCsvFile(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    if (urlValidator.isValid(url)) {
      try {
        br = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(
            new GZIPInputStream(
              new URL(url).openStream()
            )
          )
        );
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }
    else {
      throw new MalformedURLException("Supplied URL: " + url + " is an invalid URL");
    }
    return br;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator
import spock.lang.Specification

class DownloadFileSpec extends Specification {
  def "Should return buffered reader for url for gzip csv file"() {
    given:
    String url = new File("src/test/resources/test_data.csv.gz").toURI().toURL()
    def downloadFile = new DownloadFile()
    downloadFile.urlValidator = Mock(UrlValidator) {
      isValid(_) >> true
    }

    when:
    def bufferedReader = downloadFile.downloadGzipCsvFile(url)

    then:
    bufferedReader.ready()
  }
}
```

BTW, the test also shows how to convert a `File` instance created from a relative path into a file URL.

P.S.: You could also use PowerMock in order to mock static methods or constructors, which would also solve the problem. But I believe that whenever you need PowerMock, it is a code smell and you should refactor, which is what I did for you.

Comment: Did you have to use byte-buddy-1.6.4 or cglib-nodep-3.2 to get the mock of UrlValidator to work?

Comment: Of course you need CGLIB for mocking classes, only interfaces can be mocked without CGLIB. Bytebuddy is not necessary, though.

Comment: I just found this answer again and want to amend: In current Spock versions, you have a choice whether you prefer Byte Buddy or CGLIB  mocks. I am recommending BB, but for most use cases, both options are fine.